# How to paginate data from complex relations

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent, eloquent-relationship

I'm getting data from a Belongstomany relationship and I'm running the paginate helper on it but it doesn't seem to work. Here's my code..

```
$transactions  = User::withAndWhereHas('drinks', function($query) use ($status, $user_id){
$query->where('cart.status', $status); })->paginate(10);
```

Here's my table structure

I have two tables with a pivot table

Table user

```
id | name | email
```

Table drinks

```
id | name
```

Pivot Table user_drinks

```
id | user_id | drink_id | quantity | price | status
```

Comment: Can you get data smoothly without pagination? Do you try with `dd($transactions)`? I think your problem on query

Comment: you are paginating the set of Users that are returned not the related data ... if you want to have a paginated list of 'drinks' for a single user that can be done easily

Comment: @lagbox how can that be done? Say i want to get the list of drinks with status '1' for a user ?

Comment: @xNoJustice yes i can see all data when i dd()

Comment: you could try `$user = User::find(...); $drinks = $user->drinks()->where('status', 1)->paginate(...);`

Comment: @lagbox thanks, i've edited my question, i actually want to get the status off pivot table

Comment: np, you should probably show those tables involved, their structure and the relationships, then people's answers can be more accurate to your specific question

Comment: @lagbox I just did, thanks.